# How to get the first element from the result of db.collection.find(...)?

Tags: mongodb

I have an array which is the result from `db.zips.find()`.

```
sample_training> a = db.zips.find({"pop": 9999})
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5c8eccc1caa187d17ca6ed18"),
    city: 'ACMAR',
    zip: '88888',
    loc: { y: 33.584132, x: 86.51557 },
    pop: 9999,
    state: 'AL'
  }
]
sample_training>
```

As you can see from the brackets, the result is indeed an array. But I can't get its first element. I tried:

```
sample_training> a[0]

sample_training> a.0
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:1)

> 1 | a.0
    |  ^
  2 |

sample_training>
```

both failed. How can I get it?

Comment: `find` function returns a cursor, you need to convert it to array using `toArray()`

Comment: how about `find_one()`? I don't see any criteria you're using to sort, aggregate results from your `find`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Thanks! Do you know how can I get the type of an object in mongosh shell?